# What became of 'The last one'?

Tags: history

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_One_(software)):

> The Last One was a unique software
>   program in 1981 which
>   took input from a user and generated a
>   program in BASIC which could then be
>   run. It is an example of a program
>   generator.
>
> The software was not a programming
>   language, since unlike most
>   programming languages, programs were
>   generated by the user selecting
>   options from menus that would form the
>   basis of the generated code. This was
>   done in a logical sequence that would
>   eventually cause a program to be
>   generated in BASIC. At any time, the
>   user could elect to view a flow chart
>   showing the current progress of the
>   program's design. [2](http://www.tebbo.com/presshere/html/wf8104.htm)

But Wikipedia didn't say what became of this program. How popular/unpopular was it, and how many people use it? How and when did it meet its demise, or is it still available?

More information available [here](http://www.tebbo.com/presshere/html/wf8104.htm).

Comment: It wrote Windows ME and then faded into obscurity.

Comment: With community wiki none of the good answers would get any rep

Comment: Same about the question also.

Comment: I see no reason to wiki this - it is a legitimate non-chat question that can have a concrete answer.

Comment: That's a good question. I remember reading about it when it was first announced - and it was claimed by the developer(s) that it would be the last program ever written. I don't recall ever hearing it mentioned again...until just now. My guess is that its announcement was its public debut and finale all in one go.

Comment: "was a unique software program" --- that is, it was a compiler targeting basic. Cute. Special on that platform, maybe. But hardly unique.

Comment: BTW-- the possible problem I see with this question is "Too localized", and CW wouldn't change that. Borderlie, though so I have not voted to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the history of a particular program, not programming.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the current story AFAICT: [this article](http://www.tebbo.com/presshere/html/pw8102.htm) mentions that the consulting firm they formed way back then to put TLO into play was named **DJ `AI' Systems** and is now tloconsultants.com (tlo == The Last One).  Cha-ching :-)

My guess (after a 2min site scan) is that they grew their business by continually expanding what appears to be business-oriented expert system "modules" that the generated code ran against (and also perhaps even assisted in or guided some of the code generation, most likely for the code that targeted its own routines) and then incorporate the knowledge of how to use the new modules back into TLO.  Very impressive, especially for 1981 and with the engine that knew when it didn't know enough -- ScHrIaTp! I wish my manager had 1/10th that functionality.

And you gotta love that it took five minutes to generate 100 bug-free lines of BASIC code.

I'm curious as to whether they ever "closed the loop" (my term) because I didn't see it mentioned (as I didn't fully read it due to that dang corporate job and its fake-time-based insanity) as to whether they actually reached the point where its own representation was manipulated within it in order to generate the next version of TLO itself.  The name "The Last One" suggests to me that David James fully understood the meaning of manifesting a piece of software capable of presenting its own representation to the user (== programmer) for modification with the end purpose being to generate its own subsequent version.

All such self-repping-and-editing programs (live processes are IMO far more difficult while being also tantalizingly more interesting) are actually, from my perspective, equivalent in the sense that they are all 'functions that transform functions that transform functions' (how about 'FtTFtTF's -- appropriately absurd and lovely, IMO :-)

Trying to wrap one's head around how to implement such a beautiful piece of software in the face of its myriad possibilities is the kind of programming puzzle that brings home why MDD is both the current brightest idea while simultaneously being rarely used in real-world projects.  Your brain better be firing on ALL cyllinders to go treading that path.  How long has it taken Simonyi and his billions?

I am also curious as to whether there are infinite variations of FtTFtTFs or just lots and lots of lots of them.

Enjoy!

"Lasting Peace and Happiness for all Human Beings!"

Comment: It seems that you can still buy (the current version of) the Last One, at http://www.tloconsultants.com/tloutil.htm, for £150.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I found a [blog article](http://teblog.typepad.com/david_tebbutt/2007/07/the-last-one-pe.html) by a person who did a major interview with the creator of "The Last One". At the time of the writing of the article (2007), he was still working with one of the creators of "The Last One". You can probably ask him what became of it.

Answer (score 6):

TRUE STORY!!!
I was the director when TLO it first came to America from England. The company spent so much time trying to find the right marketing avenue that the bubble past them by. We all did 180 seminars with crowds of 50 to 100 each in as many days. There was Scot Norton, Gil Savage, Rodger David and Richard Housand and me, Michael Bartolucci. We had  an exclusive for the US which I cry about every time I think about it. We decided to right an accounts receivable and give it away with the program. Then in a week it changed to General Ledger, then AP and so on. Had we took one idea (AR)and ran with it, I think we could of had our dream come true. It wad a viable program. We took a voice generator that was present it the 1981 Computer Conference and teamed up with them. I wrote a BASIC program while in front of 50 press members (mostly from Europe).It was error free and took about 20 minutes that created a simple database to create and it would add, change, and delete members of the database from a central menu. We did this on the third day of the Conference in Houston TX. Wen our marketing failed so did the company. I understand the original company took it into receivership and decided not to pursue it further.
That was my second job in as many years. I continued on for another 38 more very successful  years in the computer field.

Answer (score 4):

The next step of evolution were [4GL languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language) and [CASE tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_tools). After that, we have [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) and today, [MDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-driven_development).

All of those come with more or less amount of tool support to generate code from some abstract "input". All of them more of less failed for the general case since the general case isn't abstract enough to map it to some formal *and* simple input.

Today, MDD is a solution for highly repetitive tasks and other programming tasks that can be easily abstracted. Think "copy data out of XML" (highly abstract, good tool support) vs. "calculating the gravity field of a black hole" (very specific, no reuse, little tool support).

[EDIT] As for the history of "The Last One", probably no one adopted it. Code generators always were a bit neglected. My guess is that this is because of the many pitfalls: If you need a million lines of code that look all the same, then a code generator is really cool. But you never need that. You need a million lines of code that are somewhat similar, where "somewhat" is often different from line to line.

But if no one here can answer what happened to the old program, I suggest to ask this question on the respective Wikipedia discussion page (see "discussion" at the top of the wiki page). People who wrote the article might know.

Comment: What became of the last one itself? I'm curious if lots of people adopted it, or none, if it made its owner rich, etc.

Comment: I don't think this answer is helpful. The first part doesn't address the question at all, and the edit includes only guessing.

Answer (score 4):

The Last One (TLO) was written by a bloke called David James, who was funded by "Scotty" Banbury, at the time a businessman whose main interest was a company called "Hilltop Tyres", based near Axminster in Devon.

It started life as a simple program generator on 6502 based machines, particularly the Commodore Pet and the Apple II. After a while, David dropped out and Scotty morphed into the principal author. He recoded the product as a meta generator, creating a new language which could, in theory, be retargeted at other languages. He spent a lot of time on C as a target but I don't know if he got that going, as I lost contact with Scotty and the product in the early 'nineties.

These language generators were popular at that time, another being Sycero/DB which could generate both Clipper/DBase code and quite clean ANSI C.

When first put on the market, both TLO and Sycero were useful tools for the bottom end of the market and their output was used even by quite large companies. The problem was that they generally used canned modules and simple substitution to create the target programs, although I think Scotty was experimenting with something that looked a bit like a bi-directional parser, able to translate BASIC into TLO as well as the other way around.